# Click event does not fire on button created with LayoutInflater

Tags: android, xamarin, button, click, layout-inflater

I created a floating view in a service and set the callback function for the click.

```
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        var li = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService).JavaCast<LayoutInflater>();

        var myview = li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, null);

        windowManager.AddView(myview, layoutParams);

        myview.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord).Click += BackgroundService_Click;

        base.OnCreate();
    }


    private void BackgroundService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
```

The function `BackgroundService_Click()` doesn't get called when I click the button.

How can I get the clicks to work?

Answer (score 0):

Like as in java what we do is to write
Button b;
and then b.setOnClickListner();
"We also give the context where to click"
something like classname.this

then in the call, we write what action has to be performed.

check it out in your code, maybe that might help.

Comment: I added Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener to my service class and added the OnClick(View v) callback, but it doesn't get called either when I click the button. When using SetOnClickListener().

Answer (score 0):

I switched the type from `WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay` to `WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert` when setting up the `LayoutParams`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT yea, after 2 days